# Creating Large Files in Java (2gb+)

Tags: java, file-io, randomaccessfile

I'm currently working on a project to create a large random binary file (2gb to 10gb) and I'm at a loss for ideas.  Obviously writing out 10gb worth of data would take forever and I need a timely approach.  My latest idea was to create a random access file and set the size to 2+ gb but it seems that the .setLength function can't handle sizes that large.  I've also thought about just appending one file to another to get a file large enough but it seems like there is no really good way to do that quickly either.  Any ideas out there?

Comment: It's going to take time, just write it without running out of memory. You can't do multi-threading for file creation.

Comment: what are your needs in the project ? how many files are required to be generated ? and what is maximum acceptable file generating time for your needs ?

Comment: The `setLength` function of RandomAccessFile accepts a long. There is no file size it cannot create now that doesn't exceed most, if not all existing storage limits. What problem are you having using it?

Comment: I just need one file, and I was attempting to send it 2147483648 for 2gb and it was throwing an error but for 1073741824 for 1 gb it handled it fine.  I would like the file to generate in under a minute

Comment: Figured out my problem.  Thanks to Perception I noticed that I was sending the .setLength() method an int instead of a long and the error I was getting on values above 1GB was because it was switching it to a negative number due to the size constraints on integers.  Thanks for all the help, the program is up and running

Answer (score 0):

This question and the comments helped me a lot recently - to create a file of a given size, this would be a method one could write:

```
 private File createFileOfSize(String suffix, long requestedSize) throws IOException {
    File tempFile = new File(temporaryDirectory, getClass().getSimpleName() + "." + suffix);
    RandomAccessFile randomAccessFile = new RandomAccessFile(tempFile, "rw");
    randomAccessFile.setLength(requestedSize);
    randomAccessFile.close();
    return tempFile;
  }
```

... where `RandomAccessFile` is `java.io.RandomAccessFile`